# Table-cell ignores width

Tags: html, css

I have a very weird problem with my CSS it's like table-cell ignores width. I have 3 divs with

```
display: inline-table; vertical-align: middle;
```

second div have 5 divs inside with

```
display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 10%;
```

there's only 5 divs but they take 100% of their parent. When I change one of those five elements width then the others also change. Every time they fill 100% of their parent. Adding

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

doesn't work for me. I would like use flex but it must work on IE9 :/ Vertical align works perfectly.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: You essentially are changing your element to display like a table. Which in css you cant change a tables width.. its annoying. What are you trying to achieve..

Comment: Who still uses IE9? 

Comment: @Cam Thanks for advices - I totally forgot about that...

Comment: @KevinJantzer I know it's hard to believe it has to work on IE9 but it must :D hah.. but anyway I got want I wanted to achieve :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want like this?

**HTML Codes:**

```
<!-- Table Inline 1 -->
<div class="inline-table">
    <div class="table-cell">
        One
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        One
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        One
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Table Inline 2 -->
<div class="inline-table">
    <div class="table-cell">
        One
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        One
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        One
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        One
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        One
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Table Inline 3 -->
<div class="inline-table">
    <div class="table-cell">
        One
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        One
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        One
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Codes:**

```
.inline-table{
        display: inline-table;
        border: 1px solid red;
        padding: .2em;
    }
    .table-cell{
        display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;
        border: 1px dashed green;
        padding: .2em;
        width: 10%;
    }
```